# Java Image Manipulation (Game Programmers)

Tags: java, image

Please take a look at the user [Interface](http://www.mediafire.com/i/?8474hbkaetvjckh)

I am given a task of making a hardware GUI [interface](http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=8474hbkaetvjckh) in java. As you can see the GUI is full of small individual images that need to change color or texts. For example the top UDU image has SPU turning red when the GUI is notified of an alarm going off.

What is the best way to add such images to java/Netbeans? The images need to change.

Adding an individual image per label is probably the worst way to go about it?

I would appreciate any input from *Java game programmers/drag and drop developers* as they may know better about these stuffs. But everyone is more than welcome to answer.

Comment: and what have you tried so far @Mr.?

Comment: Why not just create everything on the fly?  Or, are you going to have several different images for each function (such as 2 or 3 different SPU images)?  Are you doing this for AWT or Swing, or something else?

Comment: @James Black: I have different images for different functions. Had planned to use a decorator but I think things would be faster coding-wise with image changing approach. I have very little time to finish this work.

Comment: @Neal: Image mapping and changing statically according to the harwdare events that I read through the socket, much like html rollovers. I know its probably the worst way to do it but at this time I have very little time to do anything ego-boosting. Why I asked GUI/gaming fellows is because they might know of an easy tool/api similar to flash in java. To answer your questions, I tried to do it via decorator and gave up as it is not going to save me any time.

Answer (score 1):

[JMCAD](http://jmcad.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent example of such an interface using images. Alternatively, it may be convenient to implement the `Icon` interface, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979).